# Nethereum C# how can I get balance in address?

Tags: c#, ethereum

I try to get balance in address. 
It is my code:

```
`using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Nethereum.Web3;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 Bananas().Wait();
            }

            static private async Task Bananas()
            {
                var publicKey = "0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B";
                var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/myInfura");
                //var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(publicKey);
                var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(publicKey);
                var etherAmount = Web3.Convert.FromWei(balance.Value);

                Console.WriteLine(web3);
                Console.WriteLine("Get txCount ", etherAmount);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }`
```

I installed Nethereum via PM console: [Nethereum](https://nethereum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
I use a normal link of infura. 
Why don`t I get a next result without the balance in address?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just made a console application with your code and all the data is coming back fine from Nethereum.

Your issue is with your `Console.WriteLine(...` You are passing the `etherAmount` as a `arg0` property into the `Console.WriteLine` which will not output correctly on the console when you run it.

Try this

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Nethereum.Web3;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                 Bananas().Wait();
            }

            static private async Task Bananas()
            {
                var publicKey = "0xC0b4ec83028307053Fbe8d00ba4372384fe4b52B";
                var web3 = new Nethereum.Web3.Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/myInfura");
                //var txCount = await web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(publicKey);
                var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(publicKey);
                var etherAmount = Web3.Convert.FromWei(balance.Value);

                Console.WriteLine(web3);
                Console.WriteLine("Get txCount " + etherAmount);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

ps nice 1110.337873197299357846 ETH ;) (i know it is only test ETH but we can dream)

Comment: Alternate question: If i want to send ether to 500 people(say) using c# async, how can i use TPL without waiting for each tx to finish (assuming transactions happen with increasing nonce)?

Comment: THank you, I did it in JavaScrit earlier and I want to know C# too. Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't have to wait for transaction hash . You can calculate so as to get transaction hash if you need it.